# Is it possible to compare my working copy with an arbitrary revision?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I know that from a command prompt, I could do something like

```
svn diff -rXXX foo.bar
```

to compare my working copy of `foo.bar` with the revision `XXX`, **even if this revision was on a merged branch.**

How can I do the same with TortoiseSVN? It works like a charm with past revisions on the same branch as my WC but not on different ones...

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Rob's answer I'm now able to compare a file in my working copy to a past revision that's sitting on a merged branch. The last thing I would like to know is if it's possible to manually merge some of the diffs to my working copy:

- when I right-click a revision of a given file in the *"Show log"* window and select *"Compare with working copy"*, the diff viewer (or WinMerge in my case) compares a local copy of the file at the old revision (named after the revision number, and present in a Windows temp folder) to my actual working copy
- when I shift-right-click this same file and choose "Diff with URL", the files being compared are both local copy made in Windows' temp folder, preventing me to merge some of the differences directly to my working copy...

Is there a work-around for that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way that you can accomplish this is to hold the shift key down when you right click on the file in your working copy that you want to diff.  Select TortoiseSVN->Diff with URL.  This brings up a dialog that allows you to put in the full server path name to file on the branch you want to diff against.  It also allow you to specify the Revision as well.  This brings up the TortoiseSVN diff with the 2 files and the differences.

For more information on this you can read this link:
[Viewing Differences](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html) .  This is specifically talked about in the "Differences to another branch/tag" section

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's exactly what I was looking for except for one thing: Tortoise offers me to compare the selected revision on my merged branch with a _copy_ of my WC, and not my WC directly. It's not a big deal but it prevents me to cherry pick some changes to be merged manually. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau  Can you give an example?  I am not following your scenario 100%.  When I tested it out on a working copy I had, I shift-right-clicked on a file in my local working copy and compared that against a specific revision of a file on another branch. If you give an example of your scenario I might be able help further.

Comment: @YannickBlondeau - What I did was shift-click on the file in the working copy that I wanted to diff against a branched version and did a Diff with URL.  For me that opens the TortoiseMerge window with the working copy in the left pane, and the branch version in the right pane.  Now the file I am sure was downloaded to the temp folder to do the diff, but it shows the URL in the merge window.  I clicked the switch left and right view, then right clicked the difference I wanted to merge and picked use this text block.  This copied the line into my local working copy file.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me! I achieved what I was looking for, even if it's not as straightforward as I would have expected... :)

Answer (score 13):

@Rob's answer works, of course, but requires you to look up then type in a potentially long URL. You can accomplish the same task with just a couple mouse clicks and no typing at all:

1. In Windows Explorer open the context menu of the target file and select `TortoiseSVN >> Revision Graph`.
2. Once the graph displays, click the node representing your working copy.
3. *control*+click the node you want to compare to, which may be on *any* branch.
4. Open the context menu on either selected node, and choose `compare revisions`.

In the illustration, revision 22175 is my working copy on one branch. I chose node 18568 on a different branch to compare to--both nodes are marked with a purple square.

[image: TortoiseSVN revision graph]

**2013.02.14 Update: Compare working copy, not just working base!**

Yannick, thanks for reminding me to distinguish between **working copy** and **working base**. My previous illustration was indeed comparing working *base* to any arbitrary node. The revised illustration shows how to comparing working *copy* to any arbitrary node. To do this, notice the two right-most buttons on the toolbar. The black-encircled WC button displays and highlights the working base, in this case 22175. The red-encircled WC button displays and highlights the working copy as a special red node labeled `Modified`. Once you materialize that node, you now have a modified working copy that you can touch, grab, fold, spindle, or mutilate as you see fit! You can, for example, view your working copy modifications by selecting Modified first then select the working base (22175 in this case) and compare those revisions.

Final note: when selecting the `Modified` node, order is important! Select `Modified` first *then* control+select the node to compare. This gives you a `compare revisions` choice on the context menu. If you do it the other way around, you get a `unified diff` choice only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's what I've tried before posting here but if my working copy contains uncommitted changes, they don't appear in the diff... So the comparison is not made with my working copy but with my working base instead.

Comment: This *looks* like a simpler way than the accepted answer... but in my case there is a snag - having selected "Revision Graph" am now staring at a "Getting information from repository" dialog box that says "About 1 hour and 10 minutes remaining"... Not sure if this would be a lot quicker the second time but it seems like a very long wait.

Answer (score 5):

1. Right click on the file in Windows File Explorer and click on TortoiseSVN -> Show Log.
2. Right click on the revision you need to compare with and select "Compare with working copy".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Revision graph is painfully slow when you have a long history, plus the accepted answer talks about comparing a concrete file, while the OP title was about comparing the entire working copy with a full revision.